# How to: sending ASCII control characters in serial application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

Using the simple serial program created awhile back(http://csharp.simpleserial.com/) but I am having trouble sending ASCII control commands to my serial device. I need to send: 01P00104##. Is there a certain way to modify the code so that it sends out these “ASCII unprintable character commands” for C#?

I tried:

```
      private void linkLabel_HC1_100_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
 {
        if serialPort1.IsOpen()
        { 
          serialPort1.Write( (char)2 + “01P00104##” + (char)3);
        }
  }
```

Where (char)2 and (char)3 are supposedly the character representations for the start and end of text commands. I also tried using escape codes such as \u0002 or even sendKeys.Send(“^(b)”) or ^(c) but it wont seem to work. When I use Hyperterminal or PuTTy software, I can copy and past the full command in from a notepad.txt file and it sends correctly but when I copy and past the same code into this application, I don’t get a response from the serial device. This app uses .net 2.0. The stx and etx commands in the notepad look like a small 7 and small L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`SerialPort.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551.aspx) method.

```
var content = new List<byte>();
content.Add(2); // ASCII STX
content.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("01P00104##"));
content.Add(3); // ASCII ETX
byte[] buffer = content.ToArray();
serialPort1.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: When performing the loopback test on my serial cable, your technique delivered exactly what I needed but when I connect to my serial device I get no response. Weird thing is, When I copied and pasted your techniques output from the loopback test into hyperterminal and putty, the command sent perfectly to the device which means the command you gave is correct and the cable works fine. But do you have any idea why it still didn't work in my app? Anything to do with how its being translated or write out time??? Im using a usb to serial cable, does the code need to form to this?

Comment: @member5536 How are you "receiving" the response in your program? Add the relevant things to your question.

Comment: Got your technique to work, I needed to add:                serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true; Thanks for the help